# How does os.system() share resources if I call python?

Tags: python, memory, parallel-processing, operating-system, cpu

Let's say I have a python script to read and process a csv in which each line can be processed independently. Then lets say I have another python script that I am using to call the original script using os.system() as such:

Script A:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], r) as f:
# do some processing for each line
```

Script B:

```
import os

os.system('python Script_A.py somefile.csv')
```

How are computing resources shared between Script A and Script B? How does the resource allocation change if I call Script A as a subprocess of Script B instead of a system command? What happens if I multiprocess within either of those scenarios?

To further complicate, how would the GIL play with these different instances of python?

I am not looking for a library or a solution, but rather I'd like to understand, from the lens of python, how resources would be allocated in such scenarios so that I can optimize my code to my processing use-case.

Cheers!

Comment: This is Operating System specific question, not really python one.

Comment: "How are computing resources shared between Script A and Script B? How does the resource allocation change if I call Script A as a subprocess of Script B instead of a system command?" I don't understand the distinction you are asking about here... `os.system` creates a subprocess

Comment: "To further complicate, how would the GIL play with these different instances of python?" It creates an entirely seperate Python process, it's own interpreter with it's own GIL